# Prevent Hotlinking through CSS via .htaccess within the same website

Tags: .htaccess, css, hijack

The problems I'm facing is how to prevent hotlinking from within a website. What I want to do is to block www.website.com/user/xxx from hotlinking a CSS, but allow www.website.com/user/aaa to use the CSS using .htaccess.

-Both user xxx and user aaa is using **www.mywebsite.com/css.css** css file, I only want to allow user aaa to be able to use it and not user xxx

What I manage to come up with so far is is putting a .htaccess in www.mywebsite.com to only allow user aaa to hotlink the css.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.website.com/user/aaa) [NC]
RewriteRule \.(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://website.com/donotsteal [NC,R]
```

When I put this into the .htaccess it blocks both www.website.com/user/xxx and www.website.com/user/aaa from hotlinking the css

What I want to do is allow only this page www.website.com/user/aaa to use the css and block anything else from hotlinking it.

Comment: You have opening bracket in your 2nd RewriteCond but no closing one -- is that a typo or what? Does it work if it will be removed?

Comment: Wow I can't believe I overlooked that, yes you're right I didn't close it. I just closed it and it seems that it now allows the .css to be hotlink on both (user xxx and user aaa) sadly.

Comment: You better turn rewrite debug ON and check what data is passed in `%{HTTP_REFERER}` -- maybe it is completely different URL.

Comment: Woops I misread your post. Yes I ended up having a pointless ( in there. I just removed it and every works fine now. Thanks for your advice haha.

Answer (score 1):

According to the above comments there were mismatched parenthesis in the rule. Fixing syntax apparently worked and now the rewrite rule works as expected.